# clear selenium action chains

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I am using Python 3.5 with selenium 3.4.3

[`selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement) has a `clear()` function that can clear the text in an input element.

I need to call this function from an [`ActionChains`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains). But, as the documentation says, this functions seems not to be part of this class

How can I `clear()` an `input` element from an `ActionChain`?

Comment: why you need clear? send it before the Action chain itself and then perform the action

Comment: I open a webpage that contains some `input` fields. The web browser fills the input fields automatically. I want to clear them to send my own values instead using `send_keys()`. Anyway I solved by double clicking the field and sending a Key.DELETE

Answer (score 2):

use the method `reset_actions()`

Answer (score 0):

I had an input address form, where several words text had already been entered by browser automatically. And I needed to clear the form, but methods `web_element.clear()` and `ActionChains(driver).key_press(Keys.CONTROL).key_press('a').send_keys(Key.BACKSPACE)` didn't worked (the latter highlights the whole page). The next code did worked:

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(web_element).double_click().click_and_hold().send_keys(Keys.CLEAR).send_keys(text).perform()
```

The trick is that I used `.double_click()` and `.click_and_hold()` together and then cleared the field with `.send_keys(Keys.CLEAR)` (BACKSPACE and DELETE also work)

Answer (score -2):

Try Something Like this:

```
ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("Something")).clear()
```

May have to add a click function beforehand, if so try this:

```
ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("Something")).click()
ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("Something")).clear()
```

Comment: Nope. The clear() function is missing in Python ActionChains. I'm not sure what they've done with it.